# What can supersede/inhibit the Sarbanes-Oxley act?

Tags: united-states, etf, regulation, sec

After reading an [interesting opinion piece](https://www.realclearpolitics.com/articles/2020/05/13/is_china_buying_blackrock_143185.html), the regulatory oversight that we have come to expect in the post-Enron world (via [Sarbanes-Oxley Act](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sarbanesoxleyact.asp)) seems somewhat jeopardized. Namely, the oversight on emerging markets ETFs is made out to be very limited/non-existent from the columnist's portrayal:

> There has to be someone on the buy side to pay for all this Wall
>   Street-minted SOE paper. Nearly 40% of the BlackRock-managed iShares
>   Emerging Markets ETF is represented by this Chinese paper. How much of
>   it is pure dross is hard to say, as U.S. regulators in the form of the
>   Public Company Accounting Oversight Board, established by the
>   Sarbanes-Oxley Act, are prevented from overseeing audits of these
>   companies.

However, the article doesn't mention the specifics -- simply saying regulators are "prevented" from overseeing audits. I'm assuming this is because Chinese regulators don't disclose the audits to US counterparts, but I'm not sure.

### Question

Is this oversight blackout a result of some other legislation that supersedes the Sarbanes-Oxley Act or is it more of a case of weak enforcement mechanisms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither nor. It is if anything a result of a way too US centric view of the lawmakers. It is OBVIOUS that an ETF that is focused on emerging markets will be quite heavily focused on the largest emerging market - by FAR - in the world, which is china. And those companies will not follow US laws. Bascially if you enforce US laws on that ETF - you don't have an ETF.